# Prevent Popup From Closing on click wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to prevent popup from being closing when User clicks on it. I tried it by override the OnPreviewMouseDown and setting `e.Handled` to `true`

```
protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     base.OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
     e.Handled = true;
}
```

But doing this will not fire any mouse click event on child of Popup.
I also tried `Popup.StaysOpen = true` But this also don't work(Popup closes on click).
Is there any way to prevent Popup from closing when user clicks on it???

Answer (score 2):

Set the [`Popup.StaysOpen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.staysopen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `true`:

```
<Popup StaysOpen="True"/>
```

Comment: @adnanumer "this doesn't work" is a really detailed explanation of your current problem, and of the reason why my proposed solution does not meet your requirements.

Comment: I have List Box in Popup and When I click on Listbox Item or Scroll Viewer Button, Popup closes. But `StaysOpen` property is `true`

Answer (score 0):

in your Xaml definition add this

```
<Popup StaysOpen="True"></Popup>
```

Comment: I have List Box in Popup and When I click on Listbox Item or Scroll Viewer Button, Popup closes. But `StaysOpen` property is `true`